# I have been getting W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: from android studio

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to connect android studio apps to wamp server my sql database. When i perform my test on mobile phone, it has been giving me this error.

```
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: 
Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 446:
Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: 
http://l92.168.1.2/apexStore2/user_register.php
```

I have been making sure the pc that i run my wamp server and mobile phone i use to test the app connect to the same wifi. I have added this to my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

This is my url, i have use my ipv4 address. What have seems to be the matter? How should i fix this error?

```
 private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://l92.168.1.2/apexStore2/user_login.php";
```

Comment: Have your tried opening *"http://l92.168.1.2/apexStore2/user_login.php"* in your browser?

Comment: does this open in your browser ?  http://l92.168.1.2/apexStore2/user_login.php

Comment: that is **l92** not 192 !!!

Comment: L92 is not 192. And yes, that's a lowercase L.

Comment: @Shark , Should we vote to close as typo error ?? or Post an answer saying **l92 is not 192** ?

Comment: I'm voting "off-topic > typo". Posting an answer won't really help alot of people that mistype `192` as `l92`

Comment: Thanks the error for W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException:  is being solved. But unable to resolve virtual method 424: and 446 is still there. Is there any ways to solve this problem?